# Access data in a rails form for a separate input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm developing a form using simple_form_for. I want my second input to be a collection derived from the first, but I can't figure out how to access the first input without submitting the form.

Is there some way to access a previously inputted value?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware of how to do this within RoR natively; however, this behaviour is achievable using a JavaScript tool such as [AlpineJS.dev](https://alpinejs.dev), More specifically [AlpineJS x-model](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model) to link JS data to the form input.